# get request URI from IClientMessageInspector

Tags: .net, wcf, wcf-4

I'm building REST client in WCF, however can't find a way to get the current request URI from a message inspector. It is required to create a signature for custom authentication.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it from the `Message.Properties.Via` property (`System.Uri`).

Comment: That value is "null"

Answer (score -1):

For the REST client, build it for IIS with ASP NET Compatibility enabled/required. You should be able to inspect HttpContext.Current in this scenario and discover the current request URI.

Answer (score -1):

Hope this helps

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
            var url = (request.Headers).To.OriginalString;
}
```